# Strange shading on model

Tags: modeling

[image]

hi, why the model looks weird. no double face or normal flip?

I include the blender file
[file download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u0UNv-MXXRshgoj5KhbZXGg_qbP3Kyyj)

Comment: And what should it look like? What do you consider weird? Be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You have Custom Normal Data assigned to this mesh.

Go to **Data Tab** > **Geometry Data** > **Clear Custom Split Normals Data**

[image: 1]

Comment: hi, thks. problem solve