# Strange shading after OBJ import

Tags: faces, shadows, obj

I have strange shading after importing an obj file:

[image]

[image]

When I zoom in, the face seem perfectly flat. I checked normals, they are ok. I also tried the "clear sharp" function, nothing changed. Also tried "remove by distance" but no vertecies were deleted.

I searched a bit around here for an answer that already exists, but shading issues are dime-a-dozen with very specific issues, non of them helped me.

Does anyone know what's the problem here and how to fix?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cleared custom normals?

Comment: @scurest sorry, I don't know what that is about... can you point me towards a resource where I can learn about that?

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96737/strange-shading-on-model/96740#96740).

Comment: @scurest Beautiful! That did it. Very simple.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by clearing custom normals.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. In object mode under the object menu I changed the setting from "shade smooth" to "shade flat."